# I can connect with Tor-Browser but not with Tor standalone!

Tags: 22.04, tor, tor-browser

On a same PC running Ubuntu jammy I have installed Tor-Browser and Tor (standalone) by latest version. So the problem is when I try to connect with Tor-Browser it connects after trying about 1 minute but when I try with Tor in terminal it stuck at "Bootstrapped 10%".
I don't use bridges in both of them. So what's the difference?